# Почему не работает клик на вновь созданном элементе?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот таким образом я создаю элемент:

```
var date = new Date();
  var path =  '/frontend/web/image/frontendImage/carusel/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/avatar-'+file.name;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = path; 
  img.setAttribute('class','draggable ui-widget-content');
  document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img);
```

потом пытаюсь подключить `draggable` библиотеки  таким образом

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
$("#forIMG").on('draggable','.draggable');
```

но ни тот, ни другой вариант не срабатывает. Не подскажите, почему?

Comment: `forImg` и `forIMG` наверное разные вещи. Видимо поэтому

Comment: Блин наверное :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();
var path = "http://a2.cdn.gaiaonline.com/dress-up/avatar/ava/c8/68/50f9be992a68c8_flip.png?t=1131021187_3.00_00"
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = path;
img.setAttribute('class', 'draggable ui-widget-content');
document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img);

$(".draggable").on('click', function() {
  alert('oй');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="forIMG"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так написать

```js
$("#forImg .draggable").on('click',function () {
    alert('yes');
});
```

Comment: нет не работает.